# UNION of two queries vs two result sets. Which is efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to fetch two select statements with the same number of columns.

I can do this in two ways.

1. Execute the two queries and manage result sets as two.
2. Execute the two select statements as a single query by UNION them and then I can manage result sets as one.

I want to know which method is time efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight overhead in preparing a query and executing it.  This is only going to be a factor if your queries are really simple.  Otherwise, the cost of running a query will be dominated by either running the query or the volume of results being returned.

The difference between one query and two queries is then going to be small.  MySQL does not (to the best of my knowledge) have any special optimizations for `UNION ALL` queries.  In fact, most databases don't even run the two queries in parallel.  Conversely, I don't think `UNION ALL` queries would impede any optimizations on the subquery.

So, you should do what works best for the application.  Trying to optimize performance in this way is premature.